# Limit number of rows in memory with JXLS

Tags: java, excel, performance, jxls

I would like to use a library for reading xls files, [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) looks very useful as the mapping can be configured in an XML file.

In the case I have a performance issue with very large files, is it possible to limit the number of rows in memory so that the file is read N rows at a time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature requires event based approach for reading excel files and it is currently unsupported.

You can raise an improvement in the [jxls-reader issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-reader/issues?status=new&status=open)